# Print three different columns from different datafr

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

So, I have these df:

`df_2020`

`df_2021`

`df_2022`

All dataframes have a column called 'month'. I'm trying to print all series from each df.

Also, I'll be using the method

```
df['month'].value_counts()
```

for each df

| month | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | value | value | value |
| February | value | value | value |
| March | value | value | value |
| April | value | value | value |
| May | value | value | value |
| June | value | value | value |
| etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. |

```
# Concatenating the DataFrames horizontally
combined_df = pd.concat([df_2020, df_2021, df2022], axis=1)

#But the out is all 3 df concatenated and i want only the 'month' serie
```

Comment: Okay, it is best if you create three small three row dataframes with dummy data and show and actual desired output from this dummy data.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you ok, you need to use merge:

```
new_df = pd.merge(left=df_2020, right=df_2021, on='month')
new_df = pd.merge(left=new_df, right=df_2022, on='month')
```

Let me know if this is gives your desired output

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I realized that I needed to combine the three DataFrames and then use a pivot table to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it:

```
combined_df = pd.concat([df_2020, df_2021, df_2022], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

pivot_table = combined_df.pivot_table(index='month', columns=combined_df['date'].dt.year, aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).